# How do I update the weather information within my layout in pysimplegui and show it every time I press 'refresh' within my window?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to connect my 'refresh' button to my columns/layout to be able to produce updated weather results every time I press the button. I'm having a hard time creating a function out of updating these results too as my code seems to always 'be out of reach' to what's in the function. Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import requests
import os
import time

my_url = 'https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=41.279&lon=-72.8717'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_Soup = Soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
days = page_Soup.findAll("li", {"class": "forecast-tombstone"})


sg.theme('DarkBlue1')

day_titles = [day.img['title'].split(':')[0] for day in days]

day_imgs = [day.img['src'] for day in days]

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Konrad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\weather')
weather_images = []
for day in day_imgs:
image = 'https://forecast.weather.gov/{}'.format(day) file_name = str(image.split('.gov/'[1].replace('/', '').replace('?', '').replace('&', '').replace('=', ''))

weather_images.append(file_name)
r = requests.get(image)

with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

day_shorts = [str(day.find('p', {'class': 'short-desc'}))
            .replace('<p class="short-desc">', '')
            .replace('<br/>', ' ')
            .rstrip('</p>') for day in days]

day_temps = [str(day.find('p', {'class': 'temp temp-high'}) or
            day.find('p', {'class': 'temp temp-low'}))
            .replace('<p class="temp temp-low">', '')
            .replace('<p class="temp temp-high">', '')
            .replace('<span style="color: #000000; font-weight:normal;">', '')
            .replace('</span>', '')
            .rstrip('</p>') for day in days]

columns = [
    [sg.Text(day_title, size=(10, 0), pad=(7, 0), justification='c') for day_title in day_titles],
    [sg.Image(r'C:\Users\Konrad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\weather\{}'.format(file_name), key='day_image-') for file_name in weather_images],
    [sg.Text(day_short, size=(10, 0), pad=(7, 0), justification='c') for day_short in day_shorts],
    [sg.Text(day_temp, size=(10, 0), pad=(7, 0), justification='c') for day_temp in day_temps]
]

columns += [[sg.Button('Refresh', key='-REFRESH-', bind_return_key=True), sg.Button('Exit', key='Exit-')]]

window = sg.Window('Weather', columns, alpha_channel=.8, no_titlebar=True, grab_anywhere=True, finalize=True, location=(3000, 450))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None or event == '-Exit-':
        break
    if event == '-REFRESH-':
        event, values = window.read()

window.close()
```

Comment: What exactly does the code do differently than you expect?

Comment: so I can run the script, it shows the window with the most recent information, which is great, but to get the most recent information, I would have to turn off the script and run it again. I'm trying to figure out how to update the values using the 'refresh' button.

Answer (score 1):

For simple, demo code here for you.
Just using options of method `update` of element to update the content of element. Extra button to turn on/off auto update.

[image]

```py
from random import choice
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# Get Emoji image and string
def get_data():
    name = choice(names)
    index = names.index(name)
    return name, sg.EMOJI_BASE64_LIST[index]

dictionary = {value:key for key, value in sg.__dict__.items()
    if key.startswith("EMOJI_BASE64") and type(value) != list}
names = [dictionary[key] for key in sg.EMOJI_BASE64_LIST]
size = (max(map(len, names)), 1)

# GUI start
sg.theme('DarkBlue1')

name, data = get_data()
layout = [
    [sg.Text(name, size=size, justification='center', key='TEXT')],
    [sg.Image(data=data, key='IMAGE')],
    [sg.Button('Refresh'), sg.Button('Auto ON/OFF', key='Auto')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, size=(300, 150), finalize=True)
text, image, refresh = window['TEXT'], window['IMAGE'], window['Refresh']

# Set elements extend on x direction
text.expand(expand_x=True)
image.expand(expand_x=True)
refresh.expand(expand_x=True)

timeout = None
while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=timeout)
    if event is None or event == '-Exit-':
        break
    elif event in ('Refresh', '__TIMEOUT__'):
        # Updata element
        name, data = get_data()
        text.update(value=name)
        image.update(data=data)
    elif event == 'Auto':
        # Set timeout to 0.5s for timeout event, or None for no timeout
        timeout = 500 if timeout is None else None

window.close()
```

If it take long time to get your data from web site, multi-threading is preferred and use `window.write_event_value(...)` when threading done to add a key & value tuple to the queue that is used by threads to communicate with the window.

Comment:  short-term problem sometimes with `write_event_value` but working hard to solve very soon!